# Configuring pysparkling logger with custom format

Tags: python, log4j, h2o, sparkling-water

I'm trying to productionize Python Sparkling Water application and I want to unify logging formats from my app, Spark and H2O.
I was able to modify log4j.properties in Spark home and achieve it with Spark logs, however, H2O logs doesn't have format applied (i.e. timestamp, severity are missing).

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like guys from H2O didn't hear about logging module: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/h2o/model/metrics_base.py#L669... They are happily print messages instead of use proper logging. It's sad.